# Kotlin Warning: Unnecessary safe call on a non-null receiver of type Marker

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, null

Like everyone else, I'm learning Kotlin.  And I'm trying to do it right.  So I declare a variable in my class:

```
private lateinit var mLastMarker: Marker
```

The mLastMarker keeps track of the last time I used a marker so I can delete it when making a new one (google maps api).  So when adding a new marker I first want to delete the old one:

```
// remove last marker (if it exists)
mLastMarker?.remove()

// add this marker to the map
mLastMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
```

Which makes sense to me.  I'm thinking that I'll only execute the `remove()` function if `mLastMarker` is not null.  It'll be set immediately after and will thus call `remove()` every time after the first (when there is something to remove).

But I get a warning.  the `?.` is highlighted with the warning message in the title.  What gives?  What am I missing about kotlin's null safety here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With [`lateinit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables), a `null` value will never be stored in your property. Note that its type, `Marker`, is not the nullable `Marker?` type - in fact you can't make a property that's both nullable and `lateinit`.

By using `lateinit`, you're saying that the compiler doesn't have to check for nullability at any point, and that you *always* expect a value to be there already in the property before you ever read it. If you read it before setting it, you won't get `null`, it'll instead throw an exception. You can also never set it back to an uninitialized state, if you've given it a value, because it won't accept `null` as a new value.

In general, `lateinit` is good if you want to initialize something once, before you start using it, but for some reason can't initialize it when the property is created (for example, at the construction time of a class).

If you have to check sometimes if you currently have a value, going with a nullable property might be better (although you can technically check whether a `lateinit` variable is initialized, but it's not pretty).

Comment: Ok, this is a better answer than mine because it correctly states (unlike my answer) that you cannot actually have a nullable lateinit property (I'd not actually tried that so I wasn't aware but it makes sense).

Comment: Ah, I did not really understand how lateinit works. Now I get it.  For the record, what I really wanted is to initialize my variable as null and check it as used.  So my declaration is `private var mLastMarker: Marker? = null` and the first usage is now `mLastMarker?.remove()
`, which makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
private lateinit var mLastMarker: Marker
```

Declares an instance of type `Marker`.

```
private lateinit var mLastMarker: Marker?
```

Declares an instance of type `nullable Marker`.

Hence, in your case, the null safety `?` check is redundant because `mLastMarker` cannot be null.

So:

```
mLastMarker?.remove()
```

Can be:

```
mLastMarker.remove()
```

The confusion is probably caused because you are using `lateinit`, so I assume you figured that the value *can* be `null`. It's a bit of an odd one, because as far as the compiler is concerned the value cannot be `null`, but, unless you assign the `lateinit` value somewhere before you access it, it will in fact be "essentially" `null` (not quite, but conceptually) and accessing it would throw an `UninitializedPropertyAccessException`

Sometimes you really do need a `lateinit` property, but more often than not you can avoid it. I would suggest looking at your code and seeing if you really need it to be `lateinit` or if you can instantiate it up front, or alternatively, just where it is required.